# Make link same height as parent

Tags: html, css

It seems that adding

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%
}
```

doesn't make a link the same size as the parent (`li` in this case).

```
.navbar-nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```css
blockquote,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
html,
p {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 500
}
.nav {
  background-color: #FF8F2E;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #F27000;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.brand {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.brand > h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
}
.brand-inverse {
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav navbar">
  <div class="brand brand-inverse">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="">Documentation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the only thing that I think can affect this.

How can I make the `a` inside a `li` inherit the height of its' parent?

Comment: If possible please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @Dhwani added jsfiddle as requested

Comment: is `link` the class you're trying to add to `a` ?

Comment: You have in your fiddle `.no-link` class, yet you use here `.link`, so those styles aren't used. Just change the class name and it'll work (adding `display: block` will do just fine). Just a note, be careful with `pointer-events: none`, use it when you really need it.

Comment: @Chris there is no `link` class, there is a `no-link` class, to get rid of the decorations that I forgot to remove (did some bad thinking)

Comment: @Luuk, ok so you just want the `a` to have same height as the `li`?

Comment: @Vucko oh sorry, I was using `.link` as an example, sorry for the confusion, I'll change it directly

Comment: @chris yes, sorry for the confussion

Comment: Adding `a{display: block}` **must** work (add that style and inspect the element and you'll see that the `a` uses the full parents height). However, you won't see the `cursor: pointer` because of your `pointer-events: none` style.

Comment: Remove the padding from the `.navbar-nav > ul > li` and then add the padding to the `a` tag

Comment: @Luuk, thanks for the accept. I have updated my answer with a new code snippet of a slight convenience edit for your buttons. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set your `.navbar-nav > ul > li > a` to `display: block`. You also need to define a value for the `href` of your anchor elements and remove `pointer-events: none`, in order for your links to work.

**Demo**

```css
blockquote,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
html,
p {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 500
}
.nav {
  background-color: #FF8F2E;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #F27000;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.brand {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.brand > h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
}
.brand-inverse {
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav navbar">
  <div class="brand brand-inverse">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="http://google.com">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="http://google.com">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="http://google.com">Documentation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This will solve the `height` problems you mentioned. However, I would suggest removing the padding from your `li` and give padding to the `a` elements instead. This way, the whole width of the button becomes click-able, not just the width of the text.

Here's a demo of this small change.

**Demo**

```css
blockquote,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
html,
p {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 500
}
.nav {
  background-color: #FF8F2E;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #F27000;
}
.navbar-nav > ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.brand {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.brand > h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
}
.brand-inverse {
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav navbar">
  <div class="brand brand-inverse">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="http://google.com">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="http://google.com">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="no-link"><a href="http://google.com">Documentation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of `100%` is that it will take the value of the parent.

So you have a `.link` element who's height is 100% of its parent
now the parent is a `li` tag which again has a height of `100%`.

So the `.link` doesn't know what height to take as it is trying to take the value which is `100%` and not a actual value in pixels.

So atleast your `ul` must have a height attribute set in it so that its carried out to the `li` tag and then the same can be carried to the `.link`  element

---

**Edit 1:** After you updated the Fiddle link The only change that is required to make the `a` tag to have the same height as its `li` is by adding `display:block;` also remove the `pointer-events:none;` to make the anchor tag clickable.

```
.navbar-nav > ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* pointer-events: none; */        /* remove this to make it clickable*/
  display:block;               /* add this */
}
```

Comment: as I have stated in my question, this doesn't work and just blocks the link totally

Comment: @Luuk I checked the result and I confirmed the height is same as the `li`. is'nt that what you want?? and I am not clear with this statement `just blocks the link totally`

Comment: of course, the element is now the size of the 'li' which is exactly as I wanted, but a link is no use when you can't use it, when you can't click on it, as seems the case here

Comment: @Luuk that's the issue in the code even before adding `display:block;` , you need to provide a link or element id in the `href` of the anchor tag.. else its not clickable.. its definitely not because of the `display:block` rule

Comment: The link is click-able when no `display: block` is used, with or without an href provided.

Comment: @Luuk its not clickable becaue you have added `pointer-events:none` remove it to get the anchor tag clickable.

Comment: @Luuk you always had the issue on your side.